# Arch Linux and Windows 10 dual boot

Tags: arch-linux, windows, dual-boot, uefi, gpt

I have an ASUS Z170 pro gaming motherboard. Its motherboard uses UEFI, not BIOS. I have two drives:

An SSD with Windows 10 installed.
A blank HDD.

Following the instructions [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dual_boot_with_Windows), I run `msinfo32` and get the value of BIOS mode. It says Legacy, which means it boots in BIOS-MBR mode. The wiki has different instructions for BIOS-MBR and UEFI-GPT, but I don't know which one I have because the BIOS and Windows give me different information. Should I use MBR or GPT? Also, I must find my EFI partition but I don't know which it is. In my SSD with Windows 10, I have three partitions:
`System Reserved`
`100 MB NTFS`
`Healthy (System, Active, Primary Partition)`
Which is the EFI partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows was booting in the Legacy mode on a UEFI motherboard, which is incorrect. In order for a Linux bootoader to see Windows, it must be the same type. Reinstalling Windows 10 made it boot in UEFI mode, fixing the bootloader issue. Because Windows 10 is in UEFI mode, it is best to use GPT rather than MBR. None of the listed partitions appear to be the EFI system partition. After resinstalling Windows, a new partition clearly labeled as the EFI partition was created.